# Does the distribution of cards change every run?

Tags: slay-the-spire

I've noticed that on some runs, I never see certain cards; on other runs, they seem to be all over the place.

This was particularly bad in a recent run, where I picked up three Limit Breaks but no cards that could actually give me a non-zero strength (not even the usually fairly common Flex).

Obviously, cards have a built-in rarity (going from Common to Uncommon to Rare), but it seems like there's more going on beyond that.

Is this simply confirmation bias, or does the game actually change the availability of certain cards every run?

Comment: Is this not pretty much exactly what you asked before? If you know it's random, like you mentioned in the other question....then yes, it would.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what happened - it posted a previous revision of the question after saying that there was an error posting the question. And the point is, an optimal strategy is different if there's a uniformly random chance of getting any card of a given rarity vs you have to figure out the relative rarity of certain cards on a given run

Comment: Roll a die six times, note the results. Roll that die six times again. Notice the different results. Does that mean the odds changed between the sets of rolls?

Comment: The analysis (and therefore the strategy) is different if you're [rolling red dice the first time and blue dice the second time.](http://www.descentinthedark.com/_d_/dice.php)

Comment: Why did you pick up Limit Break before you picked up any strength increasing cards?  That's just asking for a bad run.  You can't force a strategy, you've gotta use what the game gives you.

Comment: @Studoku: 1. Gambler's Fallacy: If you toss the coin 5 times and got 'heads' every time, it's fallacious to assume the next toss will be anything but 50:50 chance for 'heads'. 2. Gambler's Fallacy Fallacy: If you toss the coin 100 times and you got 'heads' every time, it's fallacious to assume the next toss will be anything but 'heads', or that the game isn't rigged, for that matter.

Answer (score 8):

Edit: First, you might be interested in the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). Understanding randomness is difficult: our human intuitions tend to point us into wrong directions as our brains are wired to find patterns that don't exist. Essentially, this says: In order to see all the cards once you need about `n*log(n) + Gamma * n` card views (or, explicitly, `72 / 1 + 72 / 2 + ... + 1`). For 72 cards this number is already about 350, a higher number than most would guess. You only see about 40 card choices, this is only about 120 cards. For the law of large numbers to start kicking in you would need to see each card many times. It gets worse when you consider rare or uncommon cards that show up less.

Given that we don't know whether the game is changing the odds, and your sample size is far too small to conclusively prove anything about the probabilities of individual cards, knowing that there are a few dozen cards, and you only get around 40 chances at a card in a run, the probability of not seeing any card is actually reasonably high assuming the distribution is random.

That said, the game does have a fair amount of events and other things whose distribution is **not** entirely random. Let's create a list:

1. The shop.

The shop's card pool is smaller than the whole card pool. It also allows you a larger selection of cards, but costs gold.

2. Boss card pools.

Bosses always give you a choice between rarer cards.

3. Floor-based card pools.

The regular card pools include more improved cards on higher floors.

4. Specific events.

There are a lot of events that always give a particular type of card. Some of them are the only source of that card. There are also some that give a particular rarity; like the whale at the start of the game that can give you a 'rare' card.

5. Unlocks

You unlock new cards as you complete runs. This can change the distribution of cards and thus what strategies are most succesful, as the new cards may push one archetype or the other. Only applicable if you have not played a lot before, as eventually you have unlocked everything and no changes happen anymore.

**Update: Exact card chances**

Cards are drawn from 6 piles of each type of rarity and upgrade state. Each pile has an equal chance of putting out any card of that category, independent of how many you have already pulled out.

Each card drawn always has a 37% chance of being an uncommon.
The chance of being a rare starts at 0%, and is improved by 1% with each common card drawn after the 2<sup>nd</sup>, then tripled if you have nloth's gift. Also consult the following table. The 'avg' row is the result of estimating the average chance using a program that draws 1M cards.

```
+---------+-------------+------------+---------------+
| Commons | Rare(fight) | Rare(shop) | Rare (nloth)  |
+---------+-------------+------------+---------------+
| 0       | 0%          | 4%         | 0%            |
| 1       | 0%          | 5%         | 0%            |
| 2       | 0%          | 6%         | 0%            |
| 3       | 1%          | 7%         | 3%            |
| 4       | 2%          | 8%         | 6%            |
| +1      | +1%         | +1%        | +3%           |
| avg     | 5.0%        | 8.6%       | 7.5%          |
+---------+-------------+------------+---------------+
```

For example, if your first selection contained three commons, on your second selection from 3 cards you would have a 1 - (0.99 * 0.9837 * 0.9774) ~ 4.81% chance of seeing at least 1 rare card.

The chance of getting upgraded cards is dependent on the Act# and ascension:

```
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| Act | Ascension < 12 | Ascension >= 12 |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 1   | 0%             | 0%              |
| 2   | 25%            | 12.5%           |
| 3   | 50%            | 25%             |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
```

Bosses always give you a choice between 3 rare cards.

Stores are even more specific: They always have 3 attacks, 2 skills, then 1 power (again which ones specifically is randomized), then 2 random colourless cards. The chance for cards from the store to be rare is much higher.

Code for the simulation below (C#)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace stsprob
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random R = new Random();
            Double s = 0.04;
            Double f = -0.02;
            Double n = -0.06;
            Double cs = 0;
            Double cf = 0;
            Double cn = 0;
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
                double p = R.NextDouble();
                if (p < s)
                {
                    cs++;
                    s = 0.04;
                }
                else if(p < 0.63) {
                    s += 0.01;
                }
                if (p < f)
                {
                    cf++;
                    f = -0.02;
                }
            else if (p < 0.63)
            {
                    f += 0.01;
                }
                if (p < n)
                {
                    cn++;
                    n = -0.06;
                }
            else if (p < 0.63)
            {
                    n += 0.03;
                }
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("Store estimate: " + (cs / 10000).ToString() + "%\r\n");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Fight estimate: " + (cf / 10000).ToString() + "%\r\n");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Fight(nloth's gift) estimate: " + (cn / 10000).ToString() + "%\r\n");
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```